# Verify that $DT^{-1}$ is equal $(DT)^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

$T(x,y) = (2x+4y,x-3y)$

Let's find the inverse $T^{-1}$

Let $u = 2x+4y$ and $v = x-3y$

Then 
$x = {1 \over 10} (3u-4v)$ and 
$y = {1 \over 10} (u-2v)$

Therefore
$T^{-1} = ({1 \over 10} (3u-4v),  {1 \over 10} (u-2v) )$

The derivative of the inverse 
$DT^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}{3 \over 10}&{1 \over 10}\\{-4 \over 10}&{-2 \over 10}\end{bmatrix}$

The derivarite of $T$:\

$DT = \begin{bmatrix}2&4\\1&-3\end{bmatrix}$

$(DT)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}{3 \over 10}&{4 \over 10}\\{1 \over 10}& {-2 \over 10}\end{bmatrix}$

I got two similar but different results, where I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: Your $x,y$ are wrong and also you when calculating $D(T^{-1})$ you seem to be mixing up rows and columns. Note that derivatives are linear so you just need to calculate inverse map correctly.

Comment: $T$ is linear, so the derivative is irrelevant. How did you find $T^{-1}$ the first time? But, yes, peek-a-boo is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula $dT^{-1} = (dT)^{-1} $ is wrong but not too much hopefully.

You have
$$T^{-1} T = id$$
So
$$dT^{-1}_{T(x)}dT_x = id$$
Which means
$$dT^{-1}_{T(x)} = (dT_x)^{-1}$$
Hence
$$dT^{-1}_{x} = (dT_{T^{-1}(x)})^{-1}$$

But here since you have linear $T$, $dT_x = T$ so these are the same. Do your computations again!